# A stored procedure that doesn't work in my PHP code but it works with a SQL Client

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a business monitor (a pannel that presents some metrics). 
To get that data I do a sql request. By the way, I used a stored procedure.
My code is :

```
public function execErrorWarnLogs($id){
        try {
            $sql = "exec [BUSINESS_MONITOR_LOGS] @id='".$id."'";            
            $req = $this->_bdd->prepare($sql);
            $req->execute();
            $res =  $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $req->closeCursor();

            return $res;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to get some data indexed by $id, I get some troubles. I got an array that has null values... However, if I execute that stored procedure with an SQL client I get results.

Is that already happened to someone here ? Can someone explain me why I get that ?

If you want more information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is $id an integer or a string?

Try using bound parameter instead. This is a example how it is working perfectly in my code:

```
public function execErrorWarnLogs($id){
    try {
        $sql = "exec BUSINESS_MONITOR_LOGS @id=:id";            
        $req = $this->_bdd->prepare($sql);
        $req->execute([
             'id' => $id
        ]);
        $res =  $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $req->closeCursor();

        return $res;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

You should use parameters for security reasons, too!

Two site notes:

---

If you do string interpolation you don't need to prepare the statement. Then you could just do:

```
$req = $this->_bdd->query($sql);
$res = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But the recommendet approach (for security) is to provide values as bound parameters and prepare the query.

---

As far as I know, you don't need $req->closeCursor() if you use Microsofts latest pdo driver for MSSQL. Whether you need closeCursor depends on the driver you use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and notes. My $id is a string. Your code doesn't work whereas it seems to be correct. What is very surprising is that my stored procedure is like : SELECT metric, value FROM table WHERE ... But when I change it to SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... I get results. I don't know why ...

Comment: Maybe you could share the code of you stored procedure?

Comment: I post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

My stored procedure :
CREATE PROCEDURE BUSINESS_MONITOR @id VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT e.METRIC_NAME, e.METRIC_VALUE
FROM MONITOR_EVENTS e
WHERE e.MAIN_ID = @id
```

END

Answer (score 0):

There are two more possible reasons:

1. Encoding issue

I would assume, that you have an encoding issue. If $id contains chars, that are out of the ascii-range, and you have another encoding, this could cause the query to fail. So check the encoding of $id and of you db connection

2. Whitespaces in $id

Maybe you have whitespaces in you id.

Comment: When I use the PDO Exception (ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) I get that : SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation (SQLExecute[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

Comment: Looks, like $id is too long.

Comment: $id is like '01e862c0-1017-1448-9ab5-1522f5cf3c3e' , is it too big ?

Comment: No. Seems ok. But the error indicated it. Maybe try using the mssql driver instead of the odbc driver? See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: I cannot install it at work, that needs to ask the I.T.   but thank you for your help. I saw something about that error. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/544293cc-084d-4323-ac7a-0cd016577b77/getting-sqlstate22001message-microsoftsql-server-native-client-110string-data-right?forum=sqldataaccess